# javascript odd/even in a form

Tags: javascript, html

I am unable to make simple javascript that take a number in the textbox and whne the button is clicked it returns the result.

```
    <html>
<head>

<body>

<form>
<input id = "evenoddinput" >

<input type="button" value="check" OnClick="check();">
</form>
<script>
function check()
{
   var v=document.getElementById("evenoddinput").value;

   if(v%2==0)
   {
     } document.write("Even");

    else
    {
     document.write("odd");
    }


}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: forget `docuent.write()`. search for `document.createElement()` and look into `Node.innerHTML` and `Node.textContent` to manipulate the DOM

Comment: getElementById and not getValueById ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct syntax to select element by `id` attribute is [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) not `getValueById`.

Also use [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) for debugging.

```js
function check() {
  var v = document.getElementById('evenoddinput').value;
  if (v % 2 == 0) {
    console.log("Even");
  } else {
    console.log("odd");
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="evenoddinput">
  <input type="button" value="check" OnClick="check();">
```

Comment: The `+` to cast, I can't find a way to stuck it in my mind ! First, He need to use the debugger because the problem was clearly written.

Comment: No, it was a nice touch. Not used enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong
it must be

```
var v=document.getElementById("evenoddinput").value;
```

Not

```
var v=document.getValueById(evenoddinput).value;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to write into page using `document.write`. Because it will replace entire page content. It is better to use a result field and write result to this field as `innerHTML`.

```js
function check() {
  var v = document.getElementById('evenoddinput').value;
  
  var result;
  if (v % 2 == 0) {
    result = "Even";
  } else {
    result = "odd";
  }
  
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
  
}
```

```html
<input id="evenoddinput">
<input type="button" value="check" OnClick="check();">

<div id="result"></div>
```